# Regex match word between second last forward slashes and number at end

Tags: regex

I need som help with a Regex match to find two groups. The first should match the word between the second last "/" and the last "/" in a url. The second match should find the number at the end of an url either before "-" or the last "/"

Example:

```
1. <a href="/damm/test1/1-4-5-34.html">Test 1</a> 
2. <a href="/damm/test1/test2/22-33-456.html">Test 2</a> 
3. <a href="/damm/test1/test2/test3/2345.html">Test 3</a>
```

where **1** match group 1 == **test1** and group 2 == **34**
where **2** match group 1 == **test2** and group 2 == **456**
where **3** match group 1 == **test3** and group 2 == **2345**

Hope it is understandable

Thanks you

**Edit**
The question was not for finding the complete solution, but more for getting hints about find the specific groups I want to find - but ofcourse im glad that Jerry could give me a solution.

Im sorry i didn't post the worked I have already tried, so here it is:

I am using gskinner RegExr for testing and can now give you an example on this site instead http://regex101.com/r/zB3oZ6

this where what I first tried

```
href="(.*?)(\d*).html\"
```

That works fine by finding the number - but when I want to get the text then it all collapse. I will try looking at this in the future: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: What language are you using? This would be much simpler by splitting first by slashes, then splitting the last element by hyphens. Also, your question mentions *<<"...find the number at the end of an url either **before** '-'...">>*, but all your examples select the number **after** the last hyphen.

Comment: Regex is really easy to learn! Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a regex glossary where you can just request one and have it spat out at you! Like maths teachers, contributors get really 'funny' if you don't show all of your working - this often results in the infamous 'what have you tried?' response. Check out this great regex tutotial. It shouldn't take you longer than an hour or so. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like that maybe...

```
href=".*?/([^/]*)/[^/]*?([0-9]+)[^0-9]+"
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zZ5xK0)

Answer (score 0):

This one works : `.*/(.*)/.*-?([0-9]+).*`

You can use it in shell :

```
echo "<a href="/damm/test1/1-4-5-34.html">Test 1</a>" | sed -r "s;.*/(.*)/.*-?([0-9]+).*;\1 \2;"
```

cf [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xF8iJ8)

Comment: It tried this, but it doens't get the last number correctly. Instead i'm getting the number after "Test **1**"

I am using C# - and the found a solution by the answer above, but thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should work:

```
([^/]*)\/(?=[^/>]*>).*?([^.-]+)\.
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/jWD8VwkDWy

Comment: Thanks you for the response. It works, but like the answer above i als0 need the hole url as a match. That where my fault not to write it in the question - but thanks :)